# How would one add a domain user to a PC from Command Prompt or PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

The usual path to add a domain user to a computer is to click on Manager User Accounts link to open the User Accounts window.  From there, you would click on the Add button, add the domain account, and set as a Standard or Administrator account.

How would one do this from the command line or PowerShell?  I have tried "net user", but this seems to be for network changes (not to add a domain account to the local PC).

Comment: Why would you need to add a domain user? If the PC is in the domain, and the user is in the domain, just log in. Do you mean cross domain? Do you want to add the domain user to a local group that they're not already a member of (e.g., Domain Users should already be in local Users)?

Comment: I agree with @Bacon Bits but perhaps Add-LocalGroupMember is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Add-LocalGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/add-localgroupmember?view=powershell-5.1) does exactly that.

Example:

```
Add-LocalGroupMember -Name "Cert Publishers" -Member domain\myUserAccount
```

where `-Name` sepcifies the name of the local group to which the user should be added.